# What is the probability that given a bin (out of $n$ bins) that it will receive no balls

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm working on a problem where there are $n$ bins. I want to know the probability that given a bin (Specific bin) that it will receive zero balls. There are $m$ balls thrown at random into the bins.

This is similar to my homework problem, but I'm looking for the formula. I'll input my specific variables after I understand it. thanks

Comment: The probability that a particular ball lands outside our specific bin is $\frac{n-1}{n}$. By independence, the probability all $m$ land outside is $\dots$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on whether the balls are distinguishable.

- Suppose that the balls are *indistinguishable*. Using [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29), the number of ways we can put $m$ balls into $n$ bins is equal to
  $$
  {n+m-1\choose n-1}.
  $$ 
  The number of ways to put $m$ balls into $n-1$ bins (we select a specific bin and do not put any balls into it) is equal to
  $$
  {n+m-2\choose n-2}.
  $$
  The probability that the selected bin will contain $0$ balls is then given by
  $$
  \frac{n+m-2\choose n-2}{n+m-1\choose n-1}=\frac{n-1}{n+m-1}.
  $$
- Suppose that the balls are *distinguishable*. Then the number of ways we can put $m$ balls into $n$ bins is equal to
  $$
  n^m.
  $$
  The number of ways to put $m$ balls into $n-1$ bins is equal to
  $$
  (n-1)^m.
  $$
  The probability that the selected bin will contain $0$ balls is then given by
  $$
  \biggl(\frac{n-1}n\biggr)^m.
  $$

Comment: Interesting. How is this effected if for each throw 2 balls are thrown (2 balls for everyone in the previous example).

Comment: @Mhsmith21 I'm afraid I don't quite follow... It doesn't matter how we place the balls in the bins as long as the outcomes of the experiment are equally likely. Now if we place $2m$ balls instead of placing $m$ balls, then both probabilies decrease since $\frac{n−1}{n+2m−1}<\frac{n−1}{n+m−1}$ and $(\frac{n−1}n)^{2m}<(\frac{n−1}n)^m$ for $n\ge2$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** What is the probability of the first ball not landing in the bin? What about the second ball? Are the events "the first ball does not go into the selcted bin" and "the second ball does not go into the selected bin" dependent or independent?

Answer (score 0):

To further Andre's response, the probability that no balls will be thrown in a certain bin is $\frac{n-1}{n}$. Every time you throw the ball in a bin, you run the risk of getting a ball in, so the probability of having a bin receive zero balls is $(\frac{n-1}{n})^m$.